# How can I reload changed JPA Repository classes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) for dynamic reloading of my webapp without build across changes. The webapp itself is Spring MVC based, uses JPA with postgres underneath and is hosted on  Tomcat. spring-loaded does most of the stuff for me to avoid build, except that it does not know how to reload changed JPA "Repository" classes.

I am exploring possibility of extending spring-loaded. What is the best way to recreate Repository beans in application context? How does spring-data do it originally codewise?